# Java installation not found in the specified folder Error - Glassfish Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I have installed OEPE and trying to configure Glassfish server. But, I am getting an Error that ' Java installation not found in the specified folder'.

I have setup JAVA_HOME in this folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Comment: Check JAVA HOME properly set or not .

Comment: I checked it with echo %JAVA_HOME% command. I get the correct location!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath' to Path as a System variable?
You can manually add it by selecting "Edit" on the Path system variable and copy-pasting the Java path into a New field.

Comment: Did this too! No luck